# VIrtualHost: Different hosts point to the same location

Tags: apache, zend-framework, virtualhost

I am trying to set virtual hosts for two Zend Framework applications. I started by changing the `system32 hosts` file.

It contains the following lines now:

```
127.0.0.1           localhost
#   ::1             localhost
127.0.0.1           quickstart
```

After that, I proceeded with changing the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file. Its current content:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin postmaster@dummy-host2.localhost
    DocumentRoot "G:\workspace\Andrew\ProjManer\public"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/localhost-access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin postmaster@dummy-host2.localhost
    DocumentRoot "G:\workspace\Andrew\quickstart\public"
    ServerName quickstart
    ServerAlias quickstart
    ErrorLog "logs/quickstart-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/quickstart-access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

If I don't add the virtual host with localhost first, I get a `"Access forbidden 403 Error message"`.
The problem now is that both point to the same location, the localhost. How am I supposed to get the second virtual host working? I used the `flushdns` also.

Comment: Do you have a line like this: `NameVirtualHost *:80` in the main Apache config file? If not try adding it

Comment: @TimFountain can I have it in the `httpd-vhosts.conf`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the ServerAlias in them unless you want say quickstart2 to go to quickstart. In that case you will do ServerAlias quickstart2. You get access forbidden because your document root in your httpd.conf doesn't have an index.php or that virtualhost doesn't have an index.php and you have -Indexes set

Other than that the virtualhost and hosts file look fine. Try restarting your browser and restarting apache.

Comment: let me see if I understood well. The document root in httpd.conf has the path to the localhost. The virtual host for the second host name has an index.php. Localhost is working now but the new host has an access forbidden message.

Comment: ok solved it. I added one more Directory tag to the httpd.conf

Comment: My localhost is in my httpd.conf and my vhost file contains additional entries for different hosts that I put in my hosts file. I keep my vhosts simple and only set the DocumentRoot and ServerName (really I should do logs to keep it less confusing and keep the main log file clean). You can also put Directory tags within a vhost btw